# Find the derivative of the function and simplify the expression into a specific format

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We are supposed to differentiate this function:

$$\left [ \log\left(\cos^2(x)+\sqrt{1+\cos^4(x)}\right)+\arctan(x)+\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right) \right ] $$ and simplify it into a format $$C\frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt{1+\cos^4(x)}},$$ where $C$ is a real number. So, I guess you can say that the task is to find $C$.

I found out that the derivative of $\arctan(x)$ and $\arcsin(\ldots)$ cancel each other out. I’m struggling with simplifying the derivative of the logarithm into the needed form. So far I’ve got:

$$ -\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos^4(x)}\sin 2x + 2\cos^3(x)\sin(x)}{\sqrt{1+\cos^4(x)}\ln(10)\left(\sqrt{1+\cos^4(x)}+\cos^2(x)\right)}
$$

$$-\frac{\sin 2x + 2\cos^3(x)\sin(x)}{\ln(10)\left(\sqrt{1+\cos^4(x)}+\cos^2(x)\right)}$$

And I guess I’m stuck here. Any hints?

Comment: $\ln (10)$ is part of thr constant $C$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, oh, well... that makes sense. But what about the cos(x)? How do I get rid of that?

Comment: FYI, the derivatives for the inverse trig terms cancel by the trig identity $\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{1+x^2}) = \tan^{-1}(1/x) = \pi/2 - \tan^{-1} x$. Also I think you've made an algebra error in getting that expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as I mentioned in the comments, the second two terms can be written as $\tan^{-1}x + \sin^{-1}(1+x^2)^{-1/2}= \tan^{-1}x + \tan^{-1}x^{-1} = \pi/2$. So their derivatives do indeed cancel out.

For the first term, the derivative of the argument of the logarithm is
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\cos^2 x + \sqrt{1+\cos^4 x}\right) &=& -2\cos x\sin x -\frac{2 \cos^3 x\sin x}{\sqrt{1+\cos^4 x}} 
\\&=& -\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\cos^4 x}}\left(\cos^2 x + \sqrt{1+\cos^4 x}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
and the result follows from applying the chain rule to the logarithm.

You must have made some algebra error in deriving the expression you gave. It looks like either a factor of $\sqrt{1+\cos^4 x}$ has escaped from the second term or it should be simply absent.

Comment: Thank you. So C = 1/ ln 10.

is that a real number though? Because C has to be a real number.

Comment: @runtotherescue $1/\ln 10 \approx 0.4343$ is definitely a real number.

Answer (score 0):

Hint…assuming that “log” means $\log_{10}$ in this question, you can simplify the whole expression, before differentiating, as $$\frac{1}{\ln 10}\operatorname{arsinh}(\cos^2 x)+\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: We haven't covered hyperbolic functions yet. Do you think that it's possible to simplify the result I've reached into the desired expression?

Comment: Try differentiating $\ln(u+\sqrt{1+u^2})$ and simplify the result as much as possible first